# How to use TypeORM with Angular Universal?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, typeorm, angular-universal

I am trying to use TypeORM in my server generated by the Angular Universal, but the Angular copile doesn't can build the pg-native throwing this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in 'D:\dev\_agile-session\node_modules\pg\lib\native'
this.debug is not a function
```

I saw that the webpack of Angular can't do this, so I created a my webpack.config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^pg-native$/)],
};
```

And change my builder at angular.json:

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
```

But doesn't work yet, always with the same error. Somebody already try to use TypeORM on Angular Universal, I saw that have a problem with the lib pg-native in typescript, have another way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't universal mean it runs on the client and can be server-side rendered? If so this will not work

Comment: I think that I can render separate in dev, but how I can merge de build?

Comment: It's a web app. The server side of your app which will always run on the server should be a separate application

Comment: The unique difference is that the server will serve each page separate, but I will bundle my TS yet. The server dist and client dist are separates.

Comment: If any of your angular components or services or whatever reference any modules from TypeORM, then you're doing something invalid

Comment: But I will call separate from a server folder

Comment: The point of a universal application is that your components can be server-side rendered. It doesn't mean that they have access to the database directly like a server application. That's not the point of ng universal. That would mean creating two angular apps

Comment: the problem is pg-native if I use another database, works :/

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, but it sounds like you must have conditional logic in your angular application that attempts to access the database when it's being server-side rendered. That does not seem good